# How to always show two datepickers and set default date in the input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two inputs, `startdate` and `enddate`, and I am using datepicker of jQuery UI.

I have two questions:

(1) How to make the datepickers always show, instead of showing upon clicking the inputs? The current code only show `enddate`'s datepicker, and it will hide when I click the other input.

(2) How to set default date for each, and display the date in the input? The current code doesn't work.

```
=== HTML ===
<input type="text" id="startdate">
<label for="startdate">Start date</label>
<input type="text" id="enddate">
<label for="enddate">End date</label>

==== JS ====
$('#startdate, #enddate').datepicker({
    maxDate: 0
});    
$('#startdate').datepicker({
    defaultDate: -30
});
$('#enddate').datepicker({
    defaultDate: 0
});
$('#startdate').datepicker('show');
$('#enddate').datepicker('show');
```

Comment: Look in to applying datepicker to a div and use altField to populate the form element you want.

Comment: It works. But I have trouble setting the defaultDate. For `startdate`, it still show the current date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on some tinkering, here's what I've come up with. Granted, i use `data` attributes to keep the information bound to each object, but you can manage the properties however you see fit (including calling `.datepicker` on each element individually with the preferences you want).

With that said:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="enddate" id="enddate" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="date" data-altfield="#startdate" data-defaultdate="-30d"></div></td>
        <td><div class="date" data-altfield="#enddate" data-defaultdate="+0d"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(function(){
    $('.date').each(function(i,e){
        var $d = $(this);
        $d.datepicker({
            altField: $d.data('altfield'),
            defaultDate: $d.data('defaultdate')
        });
    });
});
```

The above code results in [the desired result](http://jsfiddle.net/kxuLX/) (or so i can tell).