# how to get the calendar visible always in the page and selected date as a argument for another method

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

i face a problem where to display the calendar when the page loads and select the date and assign it to a variable. the calendar should not be hidden after selecting the date because user can select another date if required.

this is my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Date</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cal.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <td width="65%" colspan="2" class="textfieldalign">                                                        
<input type="hidden" name="regddate" id="regddate" maxlength="10" >
<div id="datePi" ></div>
</td>
</body>
<script>

onLoadInitCalendar();
function onLoadInitCalendar(){     
scwShow(document.getElementById('datePi'),'onClick','');return false;
}

</script>     
</html>
```

i have used `cal.js` i am not able to past the code here.

here is the sample how the calendar should look like.
[image]

Comment: thanks to the guy who down voted for giving no reason

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8836985/1551730) and fiddle as well. it may help

Comment: @Anto Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @vimalnath thanks for the post, please give me some time, will revert back with answer. Just up voting your answer and mark it as answer if it solves the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a look at [inline](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline) datepicker

```
Eg: Assign it on a div :


$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( {
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function(date, picker){
            funcCall(date);  //call you function here
        }
    });
});
function funcCall (date){
    alert('your function called with date= '+date);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgMc3/4/)

Comment: Yes vimalnath, I am able to get the calendar, how to get the date i am selected, I want to call a method with the date selected. so basically the selected date will be an argument for another method.

Comment: $("#datepicker").datepicker( 'getDate' );
this would give you the selected date.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but how to call this. I want to pass this date on click of the date on calendar.

Comment: no, I am still not getting the date. also the calendar view is very big how to control the view?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22173/discussion-between-anto-and-vimalnath)