# jQuery UI Datepicker data attribute instead of altField

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, custom-data-attribute

I was wondering if there is a way to make jQuery UIs' Datepicker use data attribute in element to that was bind to to save alternate value, instead of whole other element specified with altField option.

The documentation claims to support objects for [altField](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField).
So far I found only [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8836985/836697), which is using data attribute only as a selector for another input element.

Long story short, I'd like to achieve this:

```
<input name="mydate" type="text" value="25.8.2013" data-proc_date="2013-08-25" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Markus Vetter, I now know that I just need to make use of onClose option of datepicker.

Assuming that dateFormat is set to "d.m.yy" and altFormat would be set to "yy-mm-dd". The resulting code, which make me free of using redundant input element, looks like this:

```
onClose : function (dateText, obj) {
    var d = $.datepicker.parseDate("d.m.yy", dateText);
    var date = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", d);
    $(this).data('date_proc', date);
}
```